# Nan Undefined Nan Error (Firefox, Edge and Safari)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, date, firefox

I've made this javascript function to calculate some dates after an date input. This is the script:

```
processDateInput: function() {
    if(!this.dayInputVal || !this.monthInputVal || !this.yearInputVal || (this.$.dayInputCon.invalid || this.$.monthInputCon.invalid || this.$.yearInputCon.invalid)) {
    this.$.dateInputErrToast.show();
    return;
}
    var monthNames = ["januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"];
    var date = new Date(this.yearInputVal + "-" + parseInt(this.monthInputVal) + "-" + parseInt(this.dayInputVal)).getTime();
    var date1 = new Date(date - 24*60*60*1000*280);
    var date2 = new Date(date - 24*60*60*1000*224);
    var date3 = new Date(date - 24*60*60*1000*175);
    var date4 = new Date(date - 24*60*60*1000*105);
    var date5 = new Date(date - 24*60*60*1000*56);
    var date6 = new Date(date - 24*60*60*1000*140);
    this.date1 = date1.getDate() + " " + monthNames[date1.getMonth() ]+ " " + date1.getFullYear();
    this.date2 = date2.getDate() + " " + monthNames[date2.getMonth() ]+ " " + date2.getFullYear();
    this.date3 = date3.getDate() + " " + monthNames[date3.getMonth() ]+ " " + date3.getFullYear();
    this.date4 = date4.getDate() + " " + monthNames[date4.getMonth() ]+ " " + date4.getFullYear();
    this.date5 = date5.getDate() + " " + monthNames[date5.getMonth() ]+ " " + date5.getFullYear();
    this.date6 = date6.getDate() + " " + monthNames[date6.getMonth() ]+ " " + date6.getFullYear();
    this.$.dateResult.opened = true;
}
```

The calculated dates are shown in html trough spans. The script works great in Chrome, but when I use the script in Firefox, Safari or Edge it will return: `NaN Undefined NaN`. I cannot find what is causing this.

Comment: Please post the console screenshot

Comment: What are the values of `this.yearInputVal`, `this.monthInputVal`, and `this.dayInputVal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will tend to happen if you have an invalid date format.

I notice you use `parseInt` on your month and date inputs, which means you'll get results like `2016-2-6`, which is not a valid format as recognised by `new Date`. Instead, you will need to ensure you pad your numbers to `2016-02-06` instead, and this should work just fine.

Alternatively, try:

```
var date = new Date(this.yearInputVal, this.monthInputVal-1, this.dayInputVal).getTime();
```

This should take the year-month-day combo and give you the correct result.

Comment: Kudos (e.g., +1) for the alternative, there's no need to go through a string for this (and many reasons not to).